# How to make a condition that would check for the presence of elements in the array?

Tags: reactjs

How to make a condition that would check for the presence of elements in the array. I would like the function to add to favorites once

```
const addFavoriteCity = (state) => {
  const newFavotiteList = [...favorites, state];
  setFavorites(newFavotiteList);
  saveToLocalStorage(newFavotiteList);
  
}
```

The **favorites** array looks like **["London", "GB"]**, the firts element is the city, the second is the country.

State:

```
        city: undefined,
        country: undefined,
        lat: undefined,
        lon: undefined,
        img: undefined,
        temp: undefined,
        feel: undefined,
        descr: undefined,
        humidity: undefined,
        pressure: undefined,
        visibility: undefined,
        dt: undefined,
        hourlyForecast: [],
        dailyForecast: [],
```

Comment: What sort of values are being stored in the `favorites` array?

Comment: state.city, state.country

Comment: Can you add an example of the `favorites` array and `state` so we may see what they actually look like? Based on comments of yours below what you describe doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry! I added this to the question

Comment: Ok, thanks for updating us. Can you now clarify what a duplicate would be, or how you'd compare an object, like `state` to an array of strings? Like if `state.city` is a value in `["london", "GB"]`, or rather, if `state.city === favorites[0]`? Something like this?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-monad-eu95k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ok, so am I correct in reading your code that in `addFavoriteCity` it's `state` that is *actually* an array of `[<city>, <country>]` and that `favorites` is an array of these arrays, i.e. `[[<city>, <country>]]`? You want to search the favorites array for an element with matching city & state, right? Can you walk us through your CSB's UI?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now you can add one city to your favorites several times. I want one city to be added to favorites once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the case that `favorites` stores primitives or you are able to use strict object equality (*typically **not** the case in React*) or you can use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with a predicate function.

### `.includes`

```
const addFavoriteCity = (state) => {
  const included = favorites.includes(state);
  
  if (included) {
    // logic if value in the array
  } else {
    // logic if not in the array
  }

  ...
}
```

### `.some`

```
const addFavoriteCity = (state) => {
  const included = favorites.some(el => {
    // return some el property equals some state property, etc...
  });
  
  if (included) {
    // logic if value in the array
  } else {
    // logic if not in the array
  }

  ...
}
```

I suggest applying the condition in a functional state update so you are also correctly referencing the previous state object instead of the one closed over in callback scope.

Example:

```
const addFavoriteCity = (state) => {
  setFavorites(list => {
    if (!list.some(el => el.city === state.city && el.county === state.county)) {
      // not included, add to state
      return [...list, state];
    }

    // included, just return current state
    return list;
  })
  
  ...
}
```

### Update

`state` looks to be an array of `[<city>, <country>]` pairs while favorites is an array of these pairs, i.e. `[[<city>, <country>]]`.

Use array destructuring assignment to get `city` and `country` from the `favorites` array to compare agains `state`'s `city` and `country`.

```
const addFavoriteCity = (state) => {
  const included = favorites.some(([city, country]) => {
    const [stateCity, stateCountry] = state;
    return (
      city.toLowerCase() === stateCity.toLowerCase() &&
      country.toLowerCase() === stateCountry.toLowerCase()
    );
  });

  if (!included) {
    setFavorites((favorites) => [...favorites, state]);
  }
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-make-a-condition-that-would-check-for-the-presence-of-elements-in-the-arr]